# Vue-CLI 3.0 - how can I change the production links?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

By default in dist/index.html created such links:

```
<link href=/js/app.2e806e0c.js rel=preload as=script>
<link href=/js/chunk-vendors.bc9ee6a2.js rel=preload as=script>
<link href=/css/chunk-vendors.fc712ce5.css rel=stylesheet>
<link href=/css/app.64eef18a.css rel=stylesheet>
<script src=/js/chunk-vendors.bc9ee6a2.js></script>
<script src=/js/app.2e806e0c.js></script>
```

How can I change links to this?

```
<link href=js/app.2e806e0c.js rel=preload as=script>
<link href=js/chunk-vendors.bc9ee6a2.js rel=preload as=script>
<link href=css/chunk-vendors.fc712ce5.css rel=stylesheet>
<link href=css/app.64eef18a.css rel=stylesheet>
<script src=js/chunk-vendors.bc9ee6a2.js></script>
<script src=js/app.2e806e0c.js></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **Vue CLI 3.3+** refer to [@DoronG's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56351363/3499595)

---

You can change this via [`baseUrl`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#baseurl) option, which you have to set in a `vue.config.js` file, in your project root:

```
module.exports = {
  baseUrl: ''
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Following answer by [@yuriy636](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52039097/2355482), `baseUrl` is now [deprecated](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#baseurl), you should use [`publicPath`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath) instead:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: ""
};
```